# O que está de errado com meu codigo?

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu quero fazer um programa que verifica se algum arquivo é nulo, mas esta lançando uma exceção, o que está errado no meu codigo?:

```
    static List<string> GetFiles(string path)
    {

        string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

        List<string> filesList = new List<string>();

        foreach(string directory in directories)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);

            foreach(string f in files)
            {
                filesList.Add(directories + "\\" + f);
            }
        }
        return filesList;
    }

    private void txtB_Path_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {  }

    private void bt_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> files = GetFiles(txtB_Path.Text);

        List<string> nullFiles = new List<string>();

        List<string> nullFilesDirectories = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            foreach (string item in files)
            {

                byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(item);

                foreach (byte bytes in fileBytes)
                {
                    if (bytes == 0)
                    {
                        nullFiles.Add(fileBytes.ToString());
                        nullFilesDirectories.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            lb_NullFiles.Text = nullFiles.Count.ToString();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            lb_NullFiles.Text = "0";
        }

        try {
            if (chckB_DeleteNullFiles.Checked)
            {
                foreach (string file in nullFilesDirectories)
                {
                    File.Delete(file);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not delete files");
        }
        lb_Files.Text = files.Count.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Pode falar em português, se essa for sua "linguagem mae" ;) O nosso idioma oficial é o português.

Comment: ok valeu cara !(Agr q vi q tava no portugues kkkk)

Comment: Esqueceu de traduzir o título.

Comment: obrigado, ja editei e vou fazer o tour

Comment: Linhas 48-70 Exceção: "Não há suporte para o formato do caminho dado"

Comment: Em vez de comentar coisas relevantes à pergunta, inclua na própria pergunta. Ela ficará mais clara.

Comment: Ss, sou novo aqui, qlqr dica q tiverem para deixar mais claro...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez há uma confusão aí quanto a um arquivo ser nulo. Entendo que não é possível, o arquivo pode ser vazio / em branco / etc...

Considerando que você quer apenas buscar pelo arquivos em uma pasta, e apagar todos os arquivos que estiverem vazios, ou seja, tamanho = 0, você pode usar o seguinte código:

```
bool delArquivosVazios = true; //valor do seu checkbox
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\pasta\\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (string file in files)
{
    FileInfo obj = new FileInfo(file);
    if (obj.Length == 0 && delArquivosVazios)
        obj.Delete();
}
```

Você ainda pode especificar um filtro:

> Troque `"*.*"` por `"*.txt"` para buscar apenas arquivos de texto, por exemplo.

Você também pode mudar a opção de busca:

> `SearchOption.AllDirectories` Para a pasta informada e todos seus sub-diretórios
>
> `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly` Para apenas a pasta informada.

Comment: obrigado, vou testar

Answer (score 0):

Você está adicionando na lista de arquivos nulos o conteúdo do arquivo, ao invés do caminho dele.

Além disso, acredito que você não precise daquele loop interno lendo cada byte do arquivo... Do jeito que está, é bem possivel que todos os arquivos do diretório sejam excluídos pois podem conter um byte '0'.

Acredito que essa seria sua intenção :

```
try
{
    foreach (string item in files)
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(item);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(fileBytes.ToString())
        {    
             nullFiles.Add(fileBytes.ToString);
             lb_NullFiles.Text = nullFiles.Count.ToString();

        }
   } 
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       lb_NullFiles.Text = "0";
   }
}
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda